# Exponents in Java (simple enough)

Tags: java, exponent

Writing a loop that does sum of exponents like so: 2^0 , 2^1, 2^2 and adds them up.

Here's my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exponents {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Enter expoenent ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        int sum = 0;
        int i =  0;
        int result = (int)Math.pow(2, sum); 


       while(i <= n) {
        i++;
        sum = sum + i;  
        result += result; 
       }
        System.out.println(result);

   }
}
```

I always seem to be one off. It doesnt seem to want to add 2^0 which is 1...so I'm always 1 off.

Comment: you have to use `pow()` for each iteration and `i++` should be last line of loop

Answer (score 2):

Why are you re-evaluating the *entire* term on each iteration?

Something like

```
int term = 1;
int sum = 0;    
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){    
   sum += term;
   term *= 2;
}
```

would be *much* more efficient. Here, `n` is the number of terms: in your example, it is 3. If you want to include an extra term, then use `<= n` as the stopping condition in the `for` loop.

Moving on, consider using a `long` as the type for `term` and `sum`.

Comment: What do you intend for *=2 to do here? I know what it does, but why?

Comment: Because each successive term is twice the size of the previous one. By the way, you could use a bit wise left shift by 1 which for Java positive integral types is equivalent to multiplication by 2. It just might be faster; try it and profile the performance.

Answer (score 0):

simple it is try this.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Enter expoenent ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n;) {
            sum += (int) Math.pow(2, i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you calculate the power only once and then calculate some other sum, not the one in the problem.

Your code should be like

```
int i =  0;
int result = 0; 
while(i <= n) {
    result += Math.pow(2, i++);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

`Math.pow(2, i++)` here we calculate power of 2 and auto increment `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will result desired output.

```
     System.out.println("Enter exponent : ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        int number = 2;
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        while (i <= n) {

            sum = sum + Math.pow(number, i);
            i = i + 1;
        }
     System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems with your code:

1. You are not adding a power of 2 to `result`, you are adding `result` to itself, ie multiplying result by 2 in every iteration. So result will be 1, 2, 4, 8, ...
2. You are keeping a sum variable which is a sum of `i`. I don't see what it's purpose would be but you are not using that variable so in this case it has no effect.

What I think you are trying to do is something like:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= n;) {
    result += (int) Math.pow(2, sum); // add 2^i to the result
    i++;                           // increment i by one.
}
System.out.println(sum);
```